# Relation between essential sup norm and quotient norm

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}([a , b])$ be the space of bounded and measurable functions from a closed bounded interval $[a , b]$ into $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the sup norm. I know that this is a Banach space.

Now consider the following vector subspace of  $\mathcal{B}([a , b])$:
$$\mathcal{L}_0=\{ f :[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} │ f  =  0 \text{ almost everywhere} \}$$

I know that $\mathcal{L}_0$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}([a , b])$. Hence the quotient space $\mathcal{B}([a , b])/\mathcal{L}_0$ endowed with the quotient norm is a Banach space.

But $\mathcal{B}([a , b])/\mathcal{L}_0$  is same as the space of equivalence class of  almost everywhere equal functions of  $\mathcal{B}([a , b])$, hence can also be endowed with the essential sup norm.

Therefore my question is what is the relation between essential sup norm and quotient norm on the space $\mathcal{B}([a , b])/\mathcal{L}_0$. I mean whether these norms are equivalent or not.

Furthermore what can we say about the cardinality of the qoutient space $\mathcal{B}([a , b])/\mathcal{L}_0$. I know that the cardinality of  $\mathcal{B}([a , b])$ is same as the power set of  $\mathbb{R}$  *i.e* $\aleph_2$ . Thanks for any help.